Error Deploying Lambda Function in Image Mode Using AWS CodeCommit and CodeBuild
I am trying to create a lambda function with the help of AWS CodeCommit and AWS CodeBuild. I tried this in zip mode, but it exceeds the zip threshold set by the lambda function (50MB). So now I'm trying to use the image mode. But somehow I'm not able to push the code into ECR.
Any help would be appreiciated.
My buildspec.yml:
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
    AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: ""
    IMAGE_REPO_NAME: "deployment"
    IMAGE_TAG: "latest"
    S3_BUCKET: "deployment"

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.11
    commands:
      - nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --storage-driver=overlay2 &
      - timeout 15 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 1; done"

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com || true
      - REPOSITORY_URI=$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME

  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
      - docker tag $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"container-name","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
      - echo Updating Lambda function...
      - sed -i 's|0123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/agent-deployment|'$REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG'|' template.yaml
      - pip install aws-sam-cli
      - sam package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template-file packaged.yaml

artifacts:
  files:
    - packaged.yaml
    - imagedefinitions.json

My template.yml :
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      ImageUri: 0123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/agent-deployment
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Environment:
        Variables:
          PARAM1: "value1"
      Events:
        HttpApi:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: GET

Outputs:
  LambdaFunction:
    Description: "Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt MyLambdaFunction.Arn
  LambdaFunctionUrl:
    Description: "Lambda Function URL"
    Value: !GetAtt MyLambdaFunction.FunctionUrl


Logs :


